# Each module must have a unique path error

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have opened a projet intellij and i got this error and i don't understand why and how resolve that

```
ERROR: The modules ['BookyMcBookface-master.app', 'app'] point to the same directory in the file 
system.
Each module must have a unique path.
```

Comment: Is it possible to share project example? It looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file .idea/modules.xml and edit the path for one the projects.